# How to repeat (recursive) query, again and again?

Tags: sqlite

**[EDIT]**

Ah.. How can I put "IF" condition when iterate ? sometimes there are no Tags at all.

In that case I do not want any kind of modification.

---

I wrote query like this;

```
UPDATE myTable SET myCOL = 
substr(myCOL, 1, instr(myCOL, '<Tag>') - 1)
 || '■' ||      
substr(myCOL, instr(myCOL, '</Tag>') + 6, length(myCOL));
```

Because I'd like to achive like this;

[image]

```
myVar  := "abc<Tag>BuLah..BuLah..</Tag>def"
myGoal := "abc■def"
```

So far so good.

Now, things goes to the real world, I have myVar like this;

```
myVar := "abc<Tag>BuLah1..</Tag>def..ghi<Tag>BuLah2..</Tag>jkl"
```

How can I achieve my goal ?

[image]

Thanks..

---

[EDIT] Text files attached for the moment.

Link Deleted...

- 1. simple extracted text, all ROWs - 811 rows
- 2. simple extracted text, all ROWs Tags processed
- 3. simple extracted text, Tags ROWs only - 18 rows, 42 tags.

When I execute without this query, its runtime instantly. No time needed. But, when I exectue with this query, it took me 71 seconds to finish. I guess I have made some.. bad bug or something. The other XML parts have handled by the other query, this query deals above mentioned Tags only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select myCOL,
    substr(myCOL, 1, instr(myCOL, '<Tag>') - 1)
    || '■' ||      
    substr(myCOL, instr(myCOL, '</Tag>') + 6, length(myCOL)) newCOL
  from myTable
  where myCOL like '%<Tag>%'
  union all                                                     
  select c.myCOL,
    substr(c.newCOL, 1, instr(c.newCOL, '<Tag>') - 1)
    || '■' ||      
    substr(c.newCOL, instr(c.newCOL, '</Tag>') + 6, length(c.newCOL)) newCOL
  from cte c                  
  where c.newCOL like '%<Tag>%'                                                      
)  
update myTable
set myCOL = (
  select newCOL from cte
  where myTable.myCOL = cte.myCOL and cte.newCOL not like '%<Tag>%'
)           
where myCOL like '%<Tag>%';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tszzwex43BCeCvDRaYqoHe/1).
Results:

```
| myCOL            |
| ---------------- |
| abc■def          |
| abc■def..ghi■jkl |
```

Comment: Wow, Nice !! I was thingking RCTE but.. that is so far from my knoledge. I will study with your good tip. Thanks Again !!!

Comment: "demo" wow.. that is good one too, this is my first time to see that one. thanks..

Comment: You can find more here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: Yap, I have skimmed it already, up until now, it looks like alien language to me though, I will visit there again and again. Thanks tip again...

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite late though.... In the middle of the testing. It looks like that it makes performance burden. Is this one processing "the row recursive" blindly and then checks the last part's "Condition" OR firstly checks the "Condition" and processing recursive table ? I do not knw quite well... anyway it is too slow..

Comment: First of all this condition is checked for the table: `where myCOL like '%<Tag>%';` so to exclude any rows that do not contain tags. Then for each of the rows of the table the column is updated with the corresponding row from the recursive cte. A recursive cte can be a *heavy burden* in case it goes too deep, but is it your case like that? How many tags maximum can a row have? In any case I don't see any other way around than a recursive cte.

Comment: ah, right, thanks for your kind reply. the query looks very good. I have Edited main post (top down of it) for the extracted contents, for your reference, for 1 or 2 days only. thanks again.....